# find -print always prints the starting directory

Tags: find

I am trying to count how many files and folders I have recursively under a directory with 500K files with `find` (note: **recursively** and **under**). I am using the following command:

```
find my_folder -name '*' -print | wc -l
```

But I noticed something strange when running the first part:

```
find my_folder -name '*' -print
```

It always prints the folder name (`my_folder` in this example) first on the first line. This increases the file count by one in my first command

Why is that? and how can I avoid this and make sure find only prints the contents under `my_folder`?

Comment: 1. This isn't the parent directory (which would be `..`), it's the starting directory (`.`). 2. It's exactly what you're asking: traversing a directory recursively starts with the directory itself, then its contents, the contents of the subdirectories, etc. If you want to exclude the starting directory, do it explicitly, or subtract 1.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles. Do you know how I can exclude the starting directory?

Comment: `-mindepth 1` is one way, as already mentioned in two answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It matches the target directory because the pattern `*` matches `.`. Since you are looking for *files*, you should add `-type f`, to only match files.

```
find my_folder -type f
```

If you have `GNU find`, you can also use `-mindepth 1` to prevent `.` from matching.

```
find my_folder -mindepth 1
```

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the OP. Sorry if I wasn't clear in my first post

Comment: @user815423426 The second example still matches the updated question.

Comment: You are right! I probably read it too quickly (I thought it said `maxdepth`). Sorry for my confusion.

Comment: No, `.` and `..` are never included by `find` unless explicitly passed in the list of files passed to `find`.

Comment: Thanks @StephaneChazelas. I am a bit confused with your answer. Are you suggesting that `-mindepth 1` is not a proper solution here?  How can I avoid having `find` include `.` and `..`, and what explains the behavior I see in my OP then?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - I just tested it using `GNU find` and it does always match the target directory. `find /tmp` matches `/tmp` and `find` or `find .` from within `/tmp` matches `.`.

Answer (score 2):

If you really just want files, you could use `-type f`. `-mindepth 1` would prevent just directories given on the command line from matching.